# Downgrade Windows 11 to Windows 10 (starting from Windows 11)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, downgrade

Can you downgrade a new computer installed with Windows 11 down to Windows 10?

Clarification:

- I am not asking about downgrading after upgrading (like an undo). As I am aware that is possible!
- I am not stuck downgrading to Windows 10. I have a device that came with Windows 11 and want to know if I have a license for Windows 10 built in somehow. That is all.

Reasoning: My 10 year old workstation running Windows 10 does file explorer navigation faster than my new gaming laptop running Windows 11. Win 10 has immediate file explore response on an old system, where Win 11 *never* does and often has 10+ second wait times in some folders. All the same software installed -- which I keep quite minimal. Both running OneDrive.

APPEND: It was OneDrive that is making file/folder accessing slow in file explorer. It is not networked drives. I have the same OneDrive, same files/folders, on both machines, so it's Windows 10 vs. Windows 11 here, to my knowledge.

Comment: Only Windows 10 licenses can activate Windows 11, Windows 11 licenses cannot activate Windows 10, you might or might not have downgrade rights that varies between OEMs and regions.

Comment: 10+ seconds? Either Windows 11 really happen to have some serious bug that caused it on your machine particularly, or more likely, it's not really about 10 vs 11.

Comment: Are you using OneDrive or some other cloud storage on the new machine? Do you have a Quick Access link which is to a network share/path somewhere other than on the local machine?

Comment: Tom and Richie, it's OneDrive making it slow... which is also on my Windows 10 machine. There is no networking happening on either.

Comment: Why the downvote? Let me know how to fix the question instead of being silently critical without helping!

Comment: @Xonatron - You have not specified what part of the process of installing Windows 10 you are stuck on, if you have a device that came with Windows 11, then it does NOT have a license to Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am not stuck on any part. I have a device that came with Windows 11. Thanks for your answer. I'll see if I can clarify your point in my question above.

Comment: You **do not** have a Windows 10 license. As I explained in my first comment on Nov 8th. I see nothing that indicates that Microsoft offers downgrade rights to Windows 10 if you have a Windows 11 device.

Comment: @Ramhound I think unless you literally failed to have Windows 10 activated with some so-to-speak Windows 11 device/license, otherwise there's literally no point in trying to make it sound like the downgrade is impossible. Btw, recently I got Education license key from DreamSpark/Imagine. (Not KMS key whatsover.) Microsoft literally offered me one same key in both Win10 and Win11 options. Besides, why would it even bother to "differentiate" "Win11-only license" when it never appeared to have to make Win 10 licenses "Win10-only"?

Comment: @Ramhound another "evidence" that DreamSpark/Imagine "reflects" how MS "group" licenses in general is that it offers different keys for the different versions of Windows Server. It also offers a different key for the Win10/11 N option set. (So the reason it offers one same key for the same edition set of Win10/11 is unlikely that it doesn't want to offer too many free keys to uni students, but perhaps, there was never such thing as "Win11-only" license behind the scene)

Comment: @TomYan - I could be wrong but my understanding the only free upgrade being offered is Windows 10 to Windows 11 and Windows 10 licenses are no longer being sold which would suggest that Windows 11 keys are NOT compatible with Windows 10. Of course it takes less than 20 minutes to try installing Windows 10 on a OEM Windows 11 device. I don’t have one

Comment: @Ramhound The fun truth is, because "Windows 10 licenses" can be used to activate Windows 11, you can't even be sure whether your device comes with a "Windows 11 (only) license" (even if there is such a thing). Certainly there are devices that come with a sticker, but can anyone even be sure if stickers and licenses have a 1-to-1 relationship? `Of course it takes less than 20 minutes to try installing Windows 10 on a OEM Windows 11 device.` That's my point -- let's not persuade anyone with such need not to TIAS :)

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree. All evidence points to the fact they Windows 10 and Windows 11 are licensed separately. Dreamspark is an exception not generality rule.

Comment: I will try it out when I return home next week and let everyone know if it works for me... with details! I appreciate both of your help.

Comment: Please report back once you're managed to run Windows 10. Would be interesting if this really did the trick with your OneDrive Explorer folder access time issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with my current laptop when I first purchased it, so here's the method I used.
First, go to [this site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), and then select `Download Now`. Once it's downloaded, just run the installer, and it should guide you through the installation process.

Comment: Wait, so it is possible?! With a laptop that came with Windows 11 installed? All the comments and downvoting above suggested otherwise. I am about to travel, so I cannot try this out now, but will look at in next week. Thank you.